# Google Chrome shows wrong favicons

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome shows wrong favicons. There are three random favicons for all sites:

[screenshot](http://oi62.tinypic.com/28lzwvc.jpg)

I deleted favicon cache file (from disk) and cleared cache by browser command, but it still doesn't work well.

Is there any way to fix it without full reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Someone or something has set extension "Replace favicon"